# How to plot this figure?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

[image]

I'd like to plot something like above plot using python. There is one feature I like:

The figure is divided into several rectangles with different color (and number). the only approximate plot I can think is scatter plot. But a scatter plot present some points, not rectangles.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The answer probably depends on what kind of data you want to show. There are several ways to produce such a plot,

1. Using [`Rectangle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle)s with given vertices
2. Using [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) of an array on an equally spaced grid
3. Using [`pcolormesh`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh) of an array on an unequally spaced grid

Assuming that you want to plot a histogram and chosing the third option, a possible solution may look something like this (based on a [`histogram2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html))

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xedges = [0, 1, 1.5, 3, 5]
yedges = [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]

# produce histogram
x = np.random.normal(2.5, 1, 100)
y = np.random.normal(1.5, 1, 100)
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=(xedges, yedges))

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('Something')
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xedges, yedges)
im = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, H)

# label the histogram bins
for i in range(len(yedges)-1):
    for j in range(len(xedges)-1):
        ax.text( (xedges[j+1]-xedges[j])/2.+xedges[j] , 
                 (yedges[i+1]-yedges[i])/2.+yedges[i] , 
                str(H[i, j]) , ha="center", va="center", color="w", fontweight="bold")
plt.colorbar(im)        

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this perfect answer!